# wp_verify_nonce vs check_admin_referer

Tags: admin, security, nonce

What is the difference, which one should I use?

I know that wp_verify_nonce checks the time limit, and check_admin_referer I think calls wp_verify_nonce as well as checking for an admin url segment, but I'm a bit confused on which one I should use and when.

Thanks for the clarity.

Comment: Tumbleweed badge for this question?  Really?  Anyone?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I *thought* that `check_admin_referer` checked the nonce (it does call `wp_verify_nonce`, **and** the referring url. After digging into the core code I realised that it did not do this. Thinking it was a bug I reported it, and Ryan Boren replied with the following:

> Actually, if the nonce is valid the referrer should not be checked.
>   The unreliability of referrers is one of the reasons that nonces are
>   used. Nonces replace referrer checking entirely. The only time we
>   check the referrer is when handling the -1 backward compatibility
>   condition. -1 means that someone is not using nonces so we fall back
>   to referrer checking. This usage is now very rare.
>   check_admin_referer() is badly named now that it almost never does
>   referrer checking. It would be better named something like
>   check_nonce(), but we keep it as is for back compat and old times
>   sake.

So there is in fact there is no difference.

Comment: Nice digging work, thanks, that brings some clarity.

Comment: There's actually one big difference that affects usage...check_admin_referer kills the entire script with die() if the nonce isn't valid, whereas wp_verify_nonce returns false. So if there are certain normal circumstances in which the nonce will fail, use wp_verify_nonce so that the rest of the script still executes.

Comment: @SeventhSteel - you are of course right. My interpretation of the question was that the logic of checking nonces were being compared rather than what happens when its invalid

Answer (score 8):

## NO! BEWARE !!!

Don't count on `check_admin_referer()` without correct parameters! Because, in some cases **it may not `die()`**  (as opposed to your expectations), instead it will just return the `false` response.

Look through the outlined behavior of [source code](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/check_admin_referer/#source) logic:

```
function check_admin_referer( $action = -1, $query_arg = '_wpnonce' ) {
    $result   = isset( $_REQUEST[ $query_arg ] ) ? wp_verify_nonce( $_REQUEST[ $query_arg ], $action ) : false;

    //Now, "die() check"
    if ( ! $result && ( -1 !== $action || strpos( wp_get_referer(), admin_url() ) !== 0 ) ) {
        die();
    }
    return $result;
}
```

So, you need to realize what the logic does. Here breakdown:

A) if you call just `check_admin_referrer()` without parameters:

- REMEMBER, it will use the automatically built-in  `_wpnonce` value (that is 
  safe, but still remember to have exactly that field when submitting).
- As you called it without paremeters, it uses **default** `-1` value for action, leading the `die() check` **to be skipped and function will not `die()`**
- So, you should always use (when calling without parameters):

`if ( check_admin_referer() ) exit;`

B) if you want `check_admin_referrer` to die automatically, then you should always create your nonces & call it with parameters:

`check_admin_referrer($action_name, $name_field );`