# AJAX nonce with check_ajax_referer()

Tags: jquery, ajax, nonce

I want to use check_ajax_referer() to verify a WP_nonce field using AJAX. Here you can find my html element.

```
<input type="hidden" name="login_nonce" value="<?= wp_create_nonce('login_nonce'); ?>"/>
```

Using jQuery I'm sending all the values from input fields to a POST request:

```
request = $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'handle-login.php',
  data: {
    user: $('input[name="login_username"]').val(),
    pass: $('input[name="login_password"]').val(),
    security: $('input[name="login_nonce"]').val()
  },
  dataType: 'json'
});
```

In handle-login.php I'm try doing the following:

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php';

$return = array();
if( check_ajax_referer( 'login_nonce', $_POST['security'], false ) )
    $return['nonce'] = $_POST['login_nonce'];

echo $return
```

But in return I'll get nothing..
Someone knows what is up?

Answer (score 8):

Difficult to say for sure where the mistake is as you have not mentioned about your `add_action('wp_ajax_my_function','whatever_callback');`which I think you missed out on that. But your question is missing info in this respect.

This is how I would get on about this:

In your functions.php file or similar:

```
add_action(wp_ajax_handle_login, 'handle_login_ajax');
add_action(wp_ajax_nopriv_handle_login, 'handle_login_ajax');
```

**Make sure** your handle-login.php file is declared on your main php file from your plugin or theme such as functions.php

```
require_once plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'handle-login.php';
```

You should declare nonce variables and the ajax url right after your js file hook, you will be able to access these after:

```
wp_enqueue_script('wccajs',plugin_dir_url( dirname(__FILE__) ) . 'login.js',array('jquery'),'1.0',false);

wp_localize_script('wccajs','MyAjax',array( 
    'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    'security' => wp_create_nonce('handle_login')
) );
```

In your handle-login.php file:

```
function handle_login_ajax(){
    check_ajax_referer('handle_login', 'security');
    $return = array();
    echo $return;
    wp_die(); // You missed this too
}
```

Your Javascript file:

```
function send_stuff_to_server(){

var data = {
    'action': 'handle_login', // missed this same as your action hook wp_ajax_{handle_login}
    'security': MyAjax.security // We can access it this way
}

$.post(MyAjax.ajax_url, data, function (callBack) {
      console.log(callBack); // Will return nonce
});

}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

I have been having the same problems and I solved using another related ajax function:
Just changing your

`check_ajax_referer( 'login_nonce', $_POST['security'], false )`

to

```
wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['security'], 'login_nonce' )
```

seems to work and return true / false correctly. About if it's more secure one way or other I have found this info:

[wp_verify_nonce vs check_admin_referer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48110/wp-verify-nonce-vs-check-admin-referer)

Answer (score 1):

In the method `check_ajax_referer()`, the second parameter is not the nonce value, is the key of the post request param.

`check_ajax_referer( 'login_nonce', 'security', false );`