# check_admin_referer()

Tags: plugin-development, wp-admin

How to use `check_admin_referer()` ? I read this [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/check_admin_referer). But I am not clear.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [wp\_verify\_nonce vs check\_admin\_referer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48110/wp-verify-nonce-vs-check-admin-referer)

Comment: Per that post - in general you don't need to use it. You would use it in the same situations in which you might perform a nonce check - and a nonce check is sufficient. If that question does not answer your own, it would help if you could provide some context as to why and where you think you might need to use `check_admin_referer()`.